# How do I stop a playblast export that is in progress?

Tags: maya

I am exporting `.png` images (`4000x4000`) so that I can analyse the rough animation outside of Maya.

There are times, I want to cancel the play blast export. I have tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> but nothing happens.

When exporting a play blast, there is a small window on the bottom left corner of the screen. I tried closing it with my mouse but that is also ignored.

I really need a way to cancel/terminate a play blast export, currently I am killing the Maya process from PowerShell and restarting Maya.